# How do I use Microsoft ADAL for Java to do Service to Service Calls?

Tags: java, service, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I thought this time I would use Microsoft's [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) libraries  to interact with Office365.

I have an integration task to perform, so no user interaction needed, that is where I found:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

I am able to get the tokens using client credentials. But according to the article I should "only" need a client_id and client_secret.

I could not find a method on the AuthenticationContext class that suggest support for this.

I hope I am overlooking something.

I know that I can perform the HTTP requests myself, but this defeats the purpose of using the ADAL software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature you're looking for is:

```
public Future<AuthenticationResult> acquireToken(
    final String resource,
    final ClientCredential credential,
    final AuthenticationCallback callback)
```

The `ClientCredential` is created with the application's `client_id` and `client_secret`. Here's an example I borrowed from [the sample included with ADAL4J](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/master/src/samples/web-app-samples-for-adal4j/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4jsample/BasicFilter.java#L153):

```
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
    "https://graph.windows.net",
    new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret),
    null);
result = future.get();
```

(In the above, `context` is the instance of `AuthenticationContext`.)

Comment: I have a access token now with these credentials, but... When accessing (in my case) crm online, I get http 401 (unauthorized). In the Azure AD permissions there is only one option to specify and that is :     Access CRM Online as organization users. Should I start a new topic to address to issue or can you @PhilippeSignoret help me out ?

Comment: You should start a new question, but the answer is: CRM Online only supports app+user tokens (delegated permissions), not app-only. If you want your process to impersonate a user even when the user isn't there, it can be achieved by the refresh token to get new access tokens but it's a fragile (and risky) setup.